# Yii2 data tool tip for images in a grid view

Tags: gridview, yii2, tooltip, yii2-basic-app

This is related to my previous question. I want a tool-tip title to be displayed dynamically for my images when I hover over the images. I have explained the relationships in my previous question [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635197/yii2-display-multiple-images-in-gridview-row/38637328#38637328). Now I want to add data tool tip to those images. My code is below

```
  [
        'label' => 'Hazards',  
        'format' => 'raw',   
        'value' => function ($data) {
             $images = '';

    // append all images
            foreach($data->getPictogramName() as $name)     
                foreach ($data->getPictogramUrl() as $url)                   
                $images = $images.Html::img($url,['alt'=>'','width'=>'30','height'=>'30', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','data-placement'=>'left','title' => $name ,'style'=>'cursor:default;']);
            return $images;

        }
  ],
```

The issue is when i loop through the name. Every image is displayed twice. There is some looping issue. Can any1 help me find the solution . Thanks

Comment: Whats your getPictogramName() function does???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url table has also the name then you have to return url with name also.

Try modifying your getPictogramUrl function like below snippet.

```
public function getPictogramUrl()
{
    $url = [];
    foreach($this->getPictogramPath() as $path):
       $url[] = [\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/web'.$path,$this->name]; 
    endforeach;
    return $url; // returning al urls
}
```

then in your view

```
[
    'label' => 'Hazards',  
    'format' => 'raw',   
    'value' => function ($data) {

        $images = '';
        // append all images
        foreach($data->getPictogramUrl() as $url):
            $images = $images.Html::img($url[0],['alt'=>'','width'=>'30','height'=>'30', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','data-placement'=>'left','title' => $url[1],'style'=>'cursor:default;']);
        endforach; 
        return $images;
    },
],
```