# How I can Display Multiple Images on DetailView in yii2

Tags: yii2, detailview

I have this code with images src array so i want to display all images from this array

```php
    <?php
        $image = explode(',',$model->image_url);
    ?>
    <?=
        DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'request_design_id',
            'email',
            'mobile_no',
            'description',
            [
                'attribute'=>'photo',
                'value'=> Yii::getAlias("@web") . "/" .$image[0],
                'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
            ],
            'created_at',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

I have only print one image. but i want to display all images from $image array

Comment: You want to display all images inside `photo` attribute?

Comment: you can check this question answer maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635197/yii2-display-multiple-images-in-gridview-row

Or you can go with the below answer with this modification 
[
   'attribute'=>'photo',
   'value'=> function ($model) use ($images) {
      $html = '';
      foreach ($images as $img) {
         $html .= Html::img($img, ['width' => '100px', 'height' => '100px'])   
      }
      return $html;
   },
   'format' => 'raw',
],

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple html img tag with the concatenation and use the format as raw.

```
        [
            'attribute'=>'photo',
            'value'=> function ($model) {
               $html = ''; 
               foreach ($images as $img) { 
                 $html .= Html::img($img, ['width' => '100px', 'height' => '100px']) 
               } 
               return $html; 
            },
            'format' => 'raw',
         ],
```

Comment: Suggested edit
[
   'attribute'=>'photo',
   'value'=> function ($model) use ($images) {
      $html = '';
      foreach ($images as $img) {
         $html .= Html::img($img, ['width' => '100px', 'height' => '100px'])   
      }
      return $html;
   },
   'format' => 'raw',
],